# Why am I getting a null value when I pass the argument which is displayed already?

Tags: spring-mvc, handlebars.js, handlebars.java

I am trying to use handlebars in spring-mvc using helper functions.

Below is my html handlebar template:

```
<td style="color: black;">\{{index}}</td>
<td style="color: black;">\{{dev_name}}</td>
{{#equality dev_name "a"}}
     <td style="cursor:pointer;color: black;" onclick="location.href='/devboard?uid=\{{mac_address}}&cid=\{{cid}}&mid=1'">
    <a class="LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5">
    \{{mac_address}} </a>
{{/equality}}
```

Below is my registered helper in java:

```
public String equality(String a,String b,Options options) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------- "+a +"    "+b);
        Object var = "";
        try{
        var = options.fn(this);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            LOG.info(" Exception caught while comparing strings");
        }
        String returnStr = (String) var;
        return returnStr;
    }
```

On execution the dev_name is displayed in the table but the value passed is null.

I don't understand the reason behind it most probably because I am new to handlebars. Can anybody out there guide me how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through lots of links this is what I found out as a solution:

```
\{{#equality dev_name "a"}}
     <td style="cursor:pointer;color: black;" onclick="location.href='/devboard?uid=\{{mac_address}}&cid=\{{cid}}&mid=1'">
    <a class="LN1 LN2 LN3 LN4 LN5">
    \{{mac_address}} </a>
\{{/equality}}
```

This way we get dev_name in my registered helper.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are using escaping format for Handlebars.
Try removing leading backslash.

`\{{dev_name}}` will display `{{dev_name}}`

`{{dev_name}}` will resolve dev_name and display it e.g. `Some dev name` (or empty if null)

Probably, you have same issue with `\{{index}}`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But that was not the issue. backslash had been added to get the raw data. how to pass the raw data as an argument was the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, to get raw data one needs to use {{{dev_name}}} or {{&dev_name}}, as handlebars will do HTML escape by default.
\{{dev_name}} will always just show >{{dev_name}}< string literal.

Regarding null value for first parameter seems like issue with model or helper registration.